# Cannot connect to remote Oracle database from within Docker container

Tags: python, oracle, docker

I am trying to connect to a remote Oracle database from inside a docker container, but fail with the following error:

```
oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

The connection works from my host machine, and I've added port mapping and network to my docker-compose:

```
ports:
    - "80:80"
network_mode: "host"
```

I am using python and oracledb library for connection, and these are the commands:

```
import oracledb
io = '/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib'
oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=io)
dsn = 'DBNAME:1521/XXX'
connection = oracledb.connect(
        user="my_user",
        password="my_pwd",
        dsn=dsn
    )
```

At this point, I don't fully understand if there is even something that I could do, or if this error originates from the database settings, and I should contact the DB admins.

Thanks!

Comment: Your DSN is not resolving on the client side. Oracle is looking for the `tnsnames.ora` file. That said, the DSN should probably be composed as `HOSTNAME:1521/SERVICE_NAME`, or `IPADDRESS:1521/SERVICE_NAME` not `DBNAME...`, if you're using the simple naming format without tnsnames.ora.

Comment: Do you need to map port 1521?